# how to pass context arguments to advice in spring aop

Tags: aop, spring-aop

I am learning spring aop now,and I have no idea to pass context arguments  to the advice.

Note I mean the `context` arguments,not the `normal` arguments.

It is simple to pass the normal arguments,for example:

```
a join point:
public void read(String something){

}

@Aspect
public class SessionAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(String)) &&args(something)")
    public void sess() {
    }

    @Before("sess()")
    public void checkSessionExist(String something) {
        //Here
    }
}
```

Then the `something` argument will be passed to the the advice `checkSessionExist`.

But how about I want to get the context arguments like HttpSession or something else?

```
a join point:

public void listUser(){
    dao.list(User.class,.....);
}

@Aspect
public class SessionAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(String))")
    public void sess() {
    }

    @Before("sess()")
    public void checkSessionExist(String something) {
        //Here
    }
}
```

In this example,the `listUser` join point is only allowed for logined user.

So I want to check if there is a identify in the current HttpSession,so I need to get an instance of  HttpSession at the advice `checkSessionExist`.

But how to get it?

The simplest way is to add the `HttpSession` argumets to all the joit points like this:

```
public void listUser(HttpSession session){
    dao.list(User.class,.....);
}
```

However this have gone against the AOP it self. In my opinion,the join point even does not need to know the exist of the Aspect,isn't it?

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `HttpSession` via `@Pointcuts`, you could fetch `HttpSession` reference in the `@Aspect` itself

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
.getAttribute("user", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION)

@Aspect
public class SessionAspect {

    // fetch the current HttpSession attributes and use as required 
    private ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();


    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(String))")
    public void sess() {
    }

    @Before("sess()")
    public void checkSessionExist(String something) {
        //Here
    }
}
```